# Как найти все изображения и изменить размер?

Tags: imagemagick, resize, ubuntu

Как перебрать все директории и изменить размер всех изображений в ней?
Есть папка /thumb/.
В ней находятся еще папки по /годам/месяцам/.

Нужно найти все изображения, уменьшить их до 250x100, отцентровав по центру, чтобы получить точный размер в 250х100.

Как сделать crop с точным размером 250х100?

```
find thumb/ -name "*.jpg" -exec convert -resize 250х100^  {} {} \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так, вроде, работает:

```
find th/ -name "*.jpg" -exec convert -resize '250x100^' -gravity center -crop 250x100+0+0  {} {} \;
```